# I have a command that outputs a directory and I want to cd into that directory

Tags: bash, shell, command, cd-command, output

I was hoping I could just do `cd | [my command]` but it seems `cd` doesn't work from a pipe.

I want to simply `cd` into the output of `[my command]` without writing a bash script of sorts I'm hoping there is a simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 8):

In POSIX shells:

```
cd -P -- "$(mycommand)"
```

- `$(cmd)` is *command substitution*. It expands to the standard output of `cmd` minus the trailing newline characters.
- `"$(cmd)"`. Without the quotes that expansion would be subject to split+glob which we don't want here.
- `--` separates options from arguments. If you know that the output of `mycommand` won't start with `-` nor `+`, you can omit it. If not `that` output my be taken as option to `cd`
- `cd` is the command to change the current directory. However, without `-P`, it might not change to the directory given as argument if that contains `..` components.

Or you could write `cd $(mycommand)`. That would be very sloppy, but that would work provided the output of `mycommand` does not contain spaces, tabs, newline, `*`, `?`, `[` characters or `..` components and doesn't start with `-` or `+`.

Now I hear you ask, *how would I change in a directory that ends in newline characters with those commands?*

Comment: Whether `-P` is necessary really depends on what the path was intended to mean. `cd -P` could just as well end up in an unintended place (or an error) as bare `cd`.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, The way `cd` without `-P` handles a path is unique to the `cd` builtin of POSIX shells, not to any other command. Unless that command was especially designed to output a path meant to be used by the `cd` builtin of a POSIX shell (not of any other shell, not by any other command), then it should be treated as a normal path, so `-P` should be used. Now, granted, it's a corner case.

Comment: I don't share your faith that everything generating `a/b/..` paths checks whether `b` is a symlink before giving it out.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, it's a fact that `/a/b/..` as a path to any system call and to any command (except the `cd` builtin of some shells) is the parent directory of `/a/b`. If you do `ls -l /a/b/..`, you'll list the content of that directory. If you call `chdir()` on that in any language, that will take you to that directory. If you call `cd` (in POSIX shells) on it without `-P`, that may or may not take you to that directory. `cd -P` will. If something outputs `a/b/..` meaning it to be `/a`, then it can only be used by those `cd` without `-P` (note that `ls -l` or the `chdir()` of any language).

Comment: Of course, one may choose to ignore the problem which in effect is unlikely to happen just as I ignored (but hinted) to the problem of directories ending in newlines (or paths with invalid characters with `yash`, or a directory called `-`).

Comment: I understand how it works, yes. I just know from bitter experience with [a system that makes heavy use of symlinks](https://gobolinux.org/) that many, many programs do not in fact handle that case correctly, and the assumption that they always do is optimistic and fanciful. It would be nice, of course. If anything, something that outputs a path rather than using it I would have *less* faith in.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, I could see arguments for both interpretations of `symlink/..` being "correct" so IMO that's a bit of a "do what I want" -situation.

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases:

```
cd `my command`
```

where `my command` is enclosed in back ticks.

This doesn't work if the output of the command contains “weird” characters. See [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364761) for more details.